# Windows Phone 8 file sharing

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, file-sharing

I have created an app that makes use of file types that are not standard to Windows Phone and I have registered my app to these extensions and they can be opened in my app perfectly from example the email client.

My application can modify the file as well as generate completely different ones. I then have an internal file manager page where users can delete files and choose to open then.

My problem now is that I want the user to share these files via email, Bluetooth, tap+send(nfc), etc. with a menu pretty much like the you get in the gallery(photos) app on Windows Phone. Is this a standard function that I can somehow access, or is there another standard library or anything really that I can use to as quickly as possible implement file sharing?

Comment: did you find a solution for your problem? I need to share files with my app too

Answer (score 0):

There is a `ShareMediaTask` but it is intended for sharing media files on any kind of files, so you need to implement everything by yourself.

Comment: Just to make sure, there is no way I can use this to share non media files?

Comment: ShareMediaTask only supports items in the Media Library either in the Camera Roll folder of the Saved Pictures folder